# Change of property with numbered name in Java

Tags: java, variables

I have a huge field of graphic elements in my GUI, and I need to change their property according to value I have.

I want to avoid writing out `switch`, although it will work, it seems stupid.
I have graphic properties in HBox named r0 - r200, and I want to change opacity of element corresponding with returned value from other functions.

Is there some clever way, better than:

```
switch(note.offGraphic()){

    case 0:
        flat6.setOpacity(1);
        break;
    case 1:
        flat5.setOpacity(1);
        break;
    case 2:
        flat4.setOpacity(1);
        break;
    case 3:
        flat3.setOpacity(1);
        break;
    case 4:
        flat2.setOpacity(1);
        break;
    case 5: 
        flat1.setOpacity(1);
    case 6:
        ok.setOpacity(1);
        break;
` and on and on
```

Comment: how about you make an array of your elements and then access it based on the index, then it's a one-liner

Comment: you can make practically all java a one-liner...

Comment: What is `note` and what does `offGraphic()` return? There might be a better way than using a map but without knowing the structure of your code it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Map instead, assign all the variables to a specific Integer (Key) and simply get the correct variable depending on the int entered and set that variable's opacity.

Assuming you always do the same thing in each case but on different variables of course

Comment: Why a map though?

Comment: I suppose a simple array / List would work just as well, I'd personally prefer working with a map for a case like this. Is there a performance issue with that maybe?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what `flat1` etc. are but if they are instance of some class or interface you could use a map.

(Edit: it seems you're using `javafx.scene.Node` you probably don't need any additional interface.)

Assuming your flats etc. are instances of `javafx.scene.Node` you could just use them in a map:

```
Map<Integer, Node> map = ...;
map.put( 0, flat6 );
map.put( 1, flat5 );
...
map.put( 6, ok );
...
```

Then use it like this:

```
Node n = map.get( note.offGraphic() );
if( n != null) {
  n.setOpacity(1);
}
```

Alternatively, your box could display a representation of those elements, i.e. you just provide a list of elements, select one and call `setOpacity(1)` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Create java array and insert each variable on corresponding index. Like this:

```
Object[] flats = new Object[numberOfFlats];
```

To fill it do:

```
    flats[0]=flat6;
        flats[1]=flat5;
        flats[2]=flat4;
    .....................
.........................
........
```

Now to get it use:

```
((Flat)flats[note.offGraphic()]).setOpacity(1);
```

Comment: Note: You can't call `setOpacity(1)` on `Object`.

Comment: Yes, but you can cast object to appropriate type of flat reference.